# Удаленная автоустановка приложений на андроид

Tags: android, adb, android-adb

Нужно реализовать удаленную автоустановку приложений на андроид, в среднем около 5 - 10 приложений.
Чтобы менеджер установил одно приложение на смартфон, нажал в нем кнопку и дальше пак из приложений сам установился, без высвечивания подтверждения установки от гугла.

Не могли бы вы подсказать, как в принципе это вообще возможно реализовать? До этого практически с андроидом не сталкивался, максимум на днях нужно было по быстрому сделать простой скринсейвер, это весь мой опыт :.

Пока, я додумался только к установке через адб, но для этого нужно минимум один раз подключить телефон по шнурку к пк, потом запустить скрипт установки по wifi.

Может можно как то запустить команды адб прямо на смартфоне, чтобы скачать нужные приложения, а потом командой их по очереди установить, без подключения к пк?

Или удаленно подключить смартфон к адб на пк "сервере". Поискав, нашел вариант подключить устройство к своему серверу используя Meterpreter для подключения к msfvenom, то есть по сути это будет некий бэкдор, что уже не очень хорошо звучит, и я не знаю смогу ли я как то использовать adb в msfvenom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ прост как 3 копейки. Нет, нельзя. Это была бы такая дыра в безопасности устройств, что народ бы взвыл от кучи самостоятельно устанавливающейся гадости. В теории можно как-то это провернуть на рутанутом устройстве, но а) не уверен, что это и правда возможно, и б) рутовать устройства сложнее и страшнее, чем подключать проводом к компу и включать адб

Comment: К примеру корпоративной версии это реализовано на сколько я понял https://www.android.com/intl/ru_ru/enterprise/recommended/ .  Также к примеру у того же тимвивера есть возможность открыть доступ с пк к андроиду и полностью управлять им. Неужели нет аналогичных разрешений и для установки?

Comment: Вы пользовались teamviewver для управления смартфоном? Картинка передается отвратительного качества и фреймрейта, задержка управления исчисляется в секундах. Никакой автоматизации не получить, 1) надо устанавливать тимвьювер, запускать и передавать айдишник на пк/другой смартфон 2) вы эмулируете нажатия. В теории можно на пк написать скрипты на winapi для прокликивания в нужных местах, но если ваши телефоны не идентичны - это не работает. Решение по ссылке возможно то, что вам нужно, но аналога быть не может. Оно работает внутри системы, будучи встроенно в см Андроид. Самим подобное не создать